Nested Xlookup [if not found] not functioning as expected, returning results that don't exist with exact match
I have a multi-column spill with data where some of the information is reflected incorrectly. We created a table to search if it's one of the incorrect records, I would like to search if it exists in the list, and if it does pull the value. This works as expected.
However, if no match is found, I simply want to take the value that exists already in the spill range. Essentially creating another spill range adjacent to it, where I have either the new values we 'overwrote' otherwise the original content.
My formula is below the issue is on the part where it says CHOOSECOLS(G2#,2) but is validating as if it matched with the last code:
=XLOOKUP( CHOOSECOLS(G2#,1),_Fix[Code],_Fix[Group], CHOOSECOLS(G2#,2),0)

I solved this but using the formula below, but I'm more curious as to why the [if not found] condition isn't triggering as expected despite the exact match condition.
=IF( ISERROR( VLOOKUP( CHOOSECOLS(G2#,1),_Fix,2,0) ) , CHOOSECOLS(G2#,2), XLOOKUP( CHOOSECOLS(G2#,1),_Fix[Code],_Fix[Group],0,0) )
Dummy data to use for testing



Code
Group




1
Non-billable


1
Non-billable


4
Admin


5
Admin


1
Non-billable


2
Non-billable


2
Non-billable


3
Admin


4
Admin


5
Admin


4
Admin


1
Non-billable






Code
Group




1
Billable


2
Billable


3
Non-billable




This needs BYROW() --> =BYROW(G2#,LAMBDA(α, XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(α,1),_Fix[Code],_Fix[Group],CHOOSECOLS(α,-1)))) when you are using CHOOSECOLS(G2#,2) it is not behaving wrong it is performing as it would, it returns an array for not found and takes up the first value for each occurrences

Shouldn't that second choosecols still be choosecols( a, 2) since I'm using the second column?

No, you have read my comments fully, please read it. It takes the first occurrence of not found in the array, so it is working correctly as it needs to behave. to make it work per row, you need a function like BYROW()

I think we're miscommunicating. I under it needs byrow. You end the formula with CHOOSECOLS(α,-1) and it's the -1 that has me a little confused. If I want the second column when a match is not found, should this not be CHOOSECOLS(α,2) since I'd want the second column for that row if I don't find a match?

CHOOSECOLS() is returning an whole array, not the respective cell value. Please try on blank cell! Both are same CHOOSECOLS(α,2) and CHOOSECOLS(α,-1)

This should accomplish the desired output, using BYROW() function:

=BYROW(G2#,LAMBDA(α, 
 XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(α,1),_Fix[Code],_Fix[Group],
 CHOOSECOLS(α,-1))))




=BYROW(G2#,LAMBDA(α, 
     XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(α,1),_Fix[Code],_Fix[Group],
     CHOOSECOLS(α,2))))


Here is a dummy data to show the usage of CHOOSECOLS() with -ve numbers to get backward columns:


• Regular Usages:
=CHOOSECOLS(B3:E15,G2:J2)


• To get backward columns:
=CHOOSECOLS(B3:E15,L2:O2)



Can you explain why -1 and 2 are interchangeable on the final choosecols formula?

@MarkS. Sir, I have used -1 you can use 2 as well, see updated screenshots, since there are only two columns it wont make any difference both are same

@MarkS. Sir, you are thinking complicatedly ! Evaluate your VLOOKUP() formula alone and do the same with XLOOKUP() without, using CHOOSECOLS() now in a blank cell use the CHOOSECOLS() to see. You will understand!

To anyone else wondering, you can use negative numbers to count backwards from the last column. Thank you for the solution, I wasn't aware you could count backwards from the end of an array by using a negative integer

CHOOSECOLS() returns an array so it gives you the first occurrence everytime for the look up functions. while using BYROW() it will perform per row and do the calculations!

Yes!, I will mimic and show you in the comments wait!

@MarkS. Sir, I have posted screenshots in the answers please take a look!

I wish i could give this another vote. My colleague and I were just discussing using column labels to populate the choosecols selections. This may make my life much easier. the next version definitely is getting this tune up

@MarkS. Sir, thank you very much for your kind words!! Just made my day!!

No need for LAMBDA here; good-old VLOOKUP does the trick:
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D13,_Fix,2,0),E2:E13)


It does but the question is why Nested XLOOKUP [if not found] not functioning as expected, returning results that don't exist with exact match

That's because the IF NOT FOUND argument does not expect an array, but a single value: Try this: =XLOOKUP({4;5;6},_Fix[Code],_Fix[Group],{"A";"B";"C"},0)

Yes that is what I tried to explain OP using XLOOKUP()

But instead of using IF(ISERROR and repeating a variant of the lookup function simply can be avoided using IFERROR, or IFNA. More efficient and better to maintain/comprehend.

I agree with that but i tried to stick with the real cause and making OP understand, that using an array with [if not found] will return the first occurrences only. While there can be many ways to do this, but for particular context one would require BYROW() with XLOOKUP() specifically, again with VLOOKUP() and CHOOSECOLS() + IFNA() we will get the same desired output. =IFNA(VLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(G2#,1),_Fix,2,0),CHOOSECOLS(G2#,2))

TRUE and well explained.

A note to be mindful of is the input is a spill range, I'm not sure if this impacts your solution or if the formula simply becomes =IFNA( VLOOKUP( choosecols(D2#,1),_Fix,2,0),choosecols(D2#,2) )

TRUE, but I didn't really see the point of the spill range, since the spill range in your post is not dynamic. But than shorter (but behaves the same) is: =ifna(VLOOKUP(take(G2#,,1),_Fix,2,0),drop(G2#,,1))

Maybe this to make it dynamic =LET(w,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(D:E,1),2),HSTACK(w,IFNA(VLOOKUP(TAKE(w,,1),_Fix,2,0),DROP(w,,1))))

In my understanding of XLOOKUP's [if_not_found] parameter, a scalar value is expected:

[if_not_found]
Where a valid match is not found, return the [if_not_found] text you supply.
If a valid match is not found, and [if_not_found] is missing, #N/A is returned.

So, similar to P.b.'s,
=IFNA(
XLOOKUP(CHOOSECOLS(G2#,1), _Fix[Code], _Fix[Group], , 0),
CHOOSECOLS(G2#, 2))

would do.
